# Parsing a multipart response with Request/Formidable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, formidable

I'm using mikeal's Request module to get images from a REST server and then trying to parse the multipart response with formidable but the form.parse never gets called.Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

```
request.get({url: "http://ur-to-get", headers: headers, qs: query}, function(err, res, body) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(res, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));      
    });
});
```

And the headers look like:

```
transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
'content-type': 'multipart/parallel;
boundary=yz2C9C5D87FD6148a3986510BCACF917A82C9C5D87FD6148a3986510BCACF917A8ZY' },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formidable's `parse` expects to be able to monitor `data` events on the `res` argument that you have passed, but because you are using `request` with a callback, your callback that creates formidable won't run until after all of the data has been emitted and collected. That's how request is able to pass the `body` argument to the callback.

The request module has a stream that you can use for data but it doesn't expose the response headers in the way Formidable wants, so I don't think there is an easy way to use it.

Since you are just doing a `GET` request, I'd recommend just using Node's default request logic instead of the `request` module, though the arguments are a bit more complicated.

```
http.get({
  host:'google.com',
  headers: headers,
  path: '/?' + querystring.stringify(qs)
}, function(res){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(res, function(err, fields, files) {
    console.log(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));      
  });
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. i didn't think of using the stream. I tried it though and it gives me the following error: "bad content-type header, no content-type"

Comment: I misread what you were saying about the headers. Why are you sending headers and transfer-encoding on a GET request? You only need those if you are sending data. Based on the error it looks like the service you are `GET`ting data from doesn't set the content-type in the response headers. Either you are requesting a bad url, or the REST service isn't doing it's job.

Comment: That's the header from the response that I am trying to parse. It's returning jpeg images. When I retieve one it sets the type as image/jpeg and when I request multiple it sets the type as multipart/parallel.

Comment: I was using Request because I'm doing multiple calls where I have to keep a cookie - Request just makes this a lot easier. I did try the HTTP and it gave me an empty array for files so maybe Formidable does have a problem with the multipart/parallel type.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.
See: [This Github Thread on Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/issues/381)